# Division in Ruby, error

Tags: ruby

it's my first day learning Ruby. I'm trying to write a Ruby program that asks the user for the cost of a meal and then what percentage they would like to tip and then does the calculation and prints out the result.  I wrote the following:

```
puts "How much did your meal cost?"
cost = gets
puts "How much do you want to tip? (%)"
tip = gets
tip_total = cost * (tip/100.0)
puts "You should tip $" + tip_total
```

When I try to run it in Terminal, I get the following error message:

```
ip_calculator.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `/' for "20\n":String (NoMethodError)
```

I have no idea what this message means, can someone help me out understanding the error message and/or with what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ip_calculator.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `/' for "20\n":String (NoMethodError)
```

> I have no idea what this message means

Let's break it down:

- `ip_calculator.rb` the file the error occured in
- `7` the line number (that's probably `tip_total = cost * (tip/100.0)`)
- `<main>` the class (`main` is Ruby's top-level class)
- `` "undefined method `/' for "20\n":String" `` error message
- `NoMethodError` exception class (http://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html)

> can someone help me out understanding the error message

The error message `` "undefined method `/' for "20\n":String" `` means, that you are attempting to call the method `/` on the object `"20\n"` which is a `String` and that this object doesn't implement such method:

```
"20\n" / 100
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for "20\n":String
```

> what is wrong with my code?

[`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns a string. `gets` doesn't attempt to interpret your input, it just passes the received characters. If you type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> in your terminal, then `gets` returns a string containing the corresponding characters `"2"`, `"0"`, and `"\n"`.

To convert the values, I'd use the built-in conversion methods [`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) or [`Kernel#Float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Float):

```
cost = Float(gets)
```

Unlike `to_i` and `to_f`, these methods will raise an error if you enter a non-numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Becuse when you enter value from STDIN it's a `String`. And ruby can not divide String to 100.

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "How much did your meal cost?"
cost = gets.to_f
puts "How much do you want to tip? (%)"
tip = gets.to_f
tip_total = cost * (tip/100.0)
puts "You should tip $ #{tip_total.round(2)}"
```

All entered values casted to `Float`s, do the calculations, and then print the rounded value.

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp]$ ./calc.rb
How much did your meal cost?
123.45
How much do you want to tip? (%)
12.43
You should tip $ 15.34
```